# OpenShift - Can I Add Multiple Cartridges for Multi-language Apps

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, openshift

I have an app that's built on rails but also uses Python for certain tasks. I can't find any documentation or figure out how to add multiple cartridges (Rails and Python) to a single app. Is this possible on OpenShift without creating my own cart? I'd think there are downloadable carts that have this config, but I can't find one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why this should be a problem. Did you try:

```
rhc cartridge add <app-name> python-2.6
```

Read [this](https://blog.openshift.com/using-rhc-to-manage-paas-apps/)